# SharePoint 2013 Patch Status

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I wonder which version of patch is correct is it 15.0.4569.1506, as it is in header or 15.0.5015.1002 both have status installed.

Zainstalowane = Installed
Zastąpione = Superseded
[image: Patch status]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single version number in SharePoint which would reliably tell you the patch level for a server or a server farm. Something like a farm patch level does not exist as SharePoint patching is pretty complex and actually means to patch various different components.

If you are facing the challenge to determine if your server is has specific fixes installed you should start with the Windows Control Panel / Programs and Features (as Trevor mentioned) which will list all the fixes installed on the box and on top the "Manage Patch Status" page in the Central admin to verify the patch status on the different servers.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/08/23/sharepoint-does-not-have-a-build-version-full-stop/